# Use of c++ lambda expression to initialize a class member

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I want to initialize one class member (`std::string filePath`) using lambda expression.
Program is compiling fine however there is no output. What is wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyString
{
  public:
  std::string filePath = [this] ()
  {
      return oneStr.append(" two");
  }();
    
  std::string oneStr;
};

int main()
{
  MyString str;
  str.oneStr = std::string(" one");
  printf("%s", str.oneStr.c_str());
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to assume that `oneStr` has been constructed yet when `filePath` is initialized.

Comment: Try to reverse the order of your members

Comment: what's your expected output? `" one two"` for `oneStr`?

Comment: @Soumyajit Roy I posted update after compiled.

Answer (score 11):

I compiled your code with clang v10.0.1 on Linux 5.8.6. Your code bumped into an core dump. Here are some logs of `valgrind` (simplified in order not to be confusing):

```
==12170== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12170==    at 0x49BEAFE: _M_check_length (basic_string.h:322)
==12170==    by 0x49BEAFE: std::string::append(char const*) (basic_string.h:1238)
==12170==    by 0x10944A: MyString::filePath::{lambda()#1}::operator()[abi:cxx11]() const (test.cc:9)
==12170==    by 0x109390: MyString::MyString() (test.cc:7)
==12170==    by 0x109270: main (test.cc:17)
```

Obviously there's something wrong with the function `append`. In fact your issue is that **you're using `oneStr` before its initialization**.

According to cppreference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

> The order of member initializers in the list is irrelevant: the actual order of initialization is as follows:
>
> ...
>
> **3) Then, non-static data member are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.**

As a result, `filePath` is initialized before `oneStr` gets initialized. The lambda is evaluated, with `this` captured, with `this->oneStr` not initialized.

---

Changing the order of declaration would fix this *undefined behavior*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyString
{
  public:
  std::string oneStr;
  std::string filePath = [this] ()
  {
      return oneStr.append(" two");
  }();
};

int main()
{
  MyString str;
  str.oneStr = std::string(" one");
  printf("%s", str.oneStr.c_str());
}
```

But still you may not get expected result (maybe  `one two`?). You will see only  `one` printed. That's because oneStr is firstly initialized with `""`, then appended with `" two"` in `MyString::MyString()`; but finally assigned with `" one"` before printing in the `main` function.

Answer (score 3):

**updated** once compiled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct MyString{
  std::string filePath = [this] () {
      return oneStr.append(" two");
  }();
    
  std::string oneStr;
};

int main(){
  MyString str; // 1 
  str.oneStr = std::string(" one"); // 2
  std::cout << str.oneStr << '\n'; // 3
}
```

At the line "1" `str` object is created.

`filePath` string is initialized first. Lambda capture `this`, but `oneStr` is not yet initialized, because is defined as second member.

Lambda is using `oneStr`, so nobody knows what is the result. Actually program crashes silently.

---

If you want the example to print " one two", do a constructor and initialize `oneStr` there.

Here is working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct MyString{
    MyString(std::string oneStr) : oneStr(std::move(oneStr)){}

    std::string oneStr;

    std::string filePath = [this] () {
        return oneStr.append(" two");
    }();    
};

int main(){
    MyString str(" one");
    std::cout << str.oneStr << '\n';
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/93xbcr

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which compiler you are using but your code in g++ gives a segmentation fault which it should since when the lambda is called oneStr doesn't exist. If you reverse the order it should work but note that the line str.oneStr=std::string("one") would replace the "two" with one. Maybe you want str.oneStr=str.oneStr+std::string("one")